# Can I declare a variable inside a lambda capture clause?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to submit a handle but I only want it to be executed if a shared pointer is still valid:

```
// elsewhere in the class:
std::shared_ptr<int> node;

// later on:
const std::weak_ptr<int> slave(node); // can I do this in the capture clause somehow?
const auto hook = [=]()
{
  if (!slave.expired())
    //do something
  else
    // do nothing; the class has been destroyed!
};

someService.Submit(hook); // this will be called later, and we don't know whether the class will still be alive
```

Can I declare `slave` within the capture clause of the lambda? Something like `const auto hook = [std::weak_ptr<int> slave = node,=]()....` but unfortunately this doesn't work. I would like to avoid declaring the variable and then copying it (not for performance reasons; I just think it would be clearer and neater if I could create whatever the lambda needs without polluting the enclosing scope).

Comment: Only in C++14, sorry to say.

Comment: @chris ah... well I've added the c++1y flag so if you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it. Cheers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this using generalized lambda captures in C++14:

```
const auto hook = [=, slave = std::weak_ptr<int>(node)]()
{
    ...
};
```

Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b22e5f1578cb4a3). Note that since there are no parameters or explicit return type, the empty parameter list (`()`) can be left out.

As pointed out in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107177), you can add `mutable` if you need to modify the captures:

```
const auto hook = [=, slave = std::weak_ptr<int>(node)]() mutable { ... }
```

Comment: Good answer, +1. Just a small addition: if one wants to change the captured variable inside the lambda (e.g. call a non-const method), the lambda has to be `mutable`.

Comment: I think you should've mentioned that `mutable` is needed if there's any attempt to modify the object defined in the lambda's capture.

Comment: @Franky, I appreciate the suggestion, and normally, I'd add that to the answer, but it's the entire point of the other answer here, right below this one.

Comment: @chris That doesn't seem like a reason to exclude it from this answer. Looks like the two answers should be combined. That one refers to this one. Supplementary information, anyway.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) this is possible in C++14.

If you are willing to modify the captured value simply add `mutable`specifier.
Here is an example which fills a vector from zero to the length of the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> container(10);

    std::generate(container.begin(), container.end(), [n = 0]() mutable { return n++; });

    for (const auto & number : container)
    {
        std::cout << number << " ";
    }

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```